# RequestPurchase: RESULT_ERROR

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have implemented the in-app billing based on the dungeons google code, but I only have 1 item, and it is managed, I can buy the item, the transaction is aproved in the google checkout, but the only response I get in the app is  "RESULT_ERROR" or error 500:

```
03-16 19:44:24.285: E/Volley(29935): [12] BasicNetwork.performRequest: 
Unexpected response code 500 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/purchase
03-16 19:44:24.295: W/Finsky(29935): [1] CheckoutPurchase.onErrorResponse:
DisplayErrorMessage[Your order is processing, your item will be available in a few     minutes.]
03-16 19:44:24.295: E/Finsky(29935): [1] CheckoutPurchase.setError:
 type=UNKNOWN, code=-1, message=Your order is processing, your item will be available in a few minutes.
```

Or this:

```
D/BillingService(30807): RequestPurchase: RESULT_ERROR
```

I'm buying the item with a test account, not the publisher account, but it's not a test item, shouldnt it work? At least the money got out ok from my card.

The market message is always:

```
your order is processing your item will be available in a few minutes
```

Comment: Is this perhaps a bug with Google Play Store? Googling for this error shows a bunch of posts on different forums in the last few weeks, but the error is rare before March 2012.

Comment: I think it is, when the items are Managed, I now have it working, but this message still appears in the Play Store, but now I just dont let the users go to the store again after they made the purchase, unless I get the cancelled or error response ofc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is strange, I didn't do anything special, just desinstalled and installed a new apk version with more debug log in it, and suddenly the server answered with the RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS request that the item was purchased, so now it is resolved.

But still if I force to go to the market and buy the item again, the same RESULT_ERROR will be sent to the app :S So I think it's a problem with the Market Server, when purchasing a MANAGED item, the response should be purchased if the same account tries to buy it again

So my new question is, despite google suggests that we only do the RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS call only when the app is first installed, but if this is the only way I got the ok from the server with a MANAGED item, should I call the RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS request, every time I open the go to market request ? (I don't have an activity for the market, the billing service starts with a button to upgrade, I only have one Upgrade item)

It's the only workaround I can think of, but I'm gonna do a few more tests with other test accounts, since it's managed item I can't buy it again.